# Entity Framework one-to-zero with different tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

I am wondering if it is possible to make one table related to many.

This is what I got now (working one-to-zero-or-one relation between `Report` and `ReportHeader`):

```
public class Report
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public ReportHeader ReportHeader {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("ReportHeader")]
  public int ReportHeaderId {get; set;}
}

public class ReportHeader
{
  [Key, ForeignKey("Report")]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public Report Report {get; set;}
}
```

At this point I want to add table named `Style` to `Report` BUT also to table `ReportHeader`. Thus, the relations would look like this:

```
Report
|--ReportHeader
|   |-- Style
|
|-- Style
```

After that the classes should look like:

```
public class Report
{
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public ReportHeader ReportHeader {get; set;}
  public Style Style {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("ReportHeader")]
  public int ReportHeaderId {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("Style")]
  public int StyleId {get; set;}
}

public class ReportHeader
{
  [Key, ForeignKey("Report")]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("Style")]
  public int StyleId {get; set;}

  public Report Report {get; set;}
  public Style Style {get; set;}
}
```

This is so much fun... until it comes to think about the `Style` class. At this point I have no idea how to design it. Is that even possible to make that class be in two relations with different tables?

```
public class Style
{
  // ???
  //[Key, ForeignKey("Report"), ForeignKey("ReportHeader")]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public ReportHeader ReportHeader {get; set;}
  public Report Report {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: What are desired relations between Report-Style and ReportHeader-Style?

Comment: Well, your `Style` needs to have two (optional) FK relationships - one to `Report`, and the other to `ReportHeader`. So add two FK columns and accordingly two navigation properties for those two references.

Comment: @Slava Utesinov Report-Style 1:1, ReportHeader-Style 1:0..1

Comment: @marc_s I just did like you said:
`public class Style
{
  public int Id {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("ReportHeader")]
  public int ReportHeaderId {get; set}
  public ReportHeader ReportHeader {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("Report")]
  public int ReportId {get; set;}
  public Report Report {get; set;}
}`

The error is : 
Style_ReportHeader_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Style_ReportHeader_Target' in relationship 'Style_ReportHeader'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this case you should to **mask** your desired relation: one-to-one as many-to-one:

```
public BaseClass
{
    //indeed, collection always will have zero or one items
    public virtual ICollection<Style> styles {get; set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public Style style {
       get { return styles.FirstOrDefault(); } 
       set { styles.Add(value); };
    }
}

public class Report : BaseClass
{
    //other stuff...
}

public class ReportHeader : BaseClass
{
    //other stuff...
}

public class Style
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public virtual Report report {get; set;}
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]//to ensure that relation is exactly one-to-one
    public int? reportId {get; set;}

    public virtual ReportHeader reportHeader {get; set;}
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]//to ensure that relation is exactly one-to-one
    public int? reportHeaderId {get; set;}
}
```